# How to return selected radiogroup value when using .each function?

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

In the following HTML, I want to only retrieving which radiogroup option
selected for that particular radiogroup.

Here is how I want this to work, I am basically going to have the user enter required values on the web page, at the same time choosing the radiogroup options available to them - is this case Yes/No, but I would then like to scan the page when they press a button, which would then just show me which radiogroup options they seleced.

So based on the following HTML code, if for the radiogroup named "married", they selected "YES" and for the radiogroup named "children" they selected "No" then I want to for now, alert to the screen:

```
YES
NO
```

only and not

```
YES
YES
NO
NO
```

I am using a .each function to scan all the elements on the page and also check to see if the type is "radio" but unfortunately I am getting duplicate responses, which I don't want.

How can I scan the page and only return just YES and NO for each of the radiogroups?

```
<fieldset class="radio_group" tabindex="-1" id="MARRIED_RG">
<table class="radiogroup" datatable="0" role="presentation" summary="">
<tbody><tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" value="YES" name="married" id="MARRIED_RG_0"><label for="MARRIED_RG_0">Yes</label></td><td nowrap="nowrap">
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" value="NO" name="married" id="MARRIED_RG_1"><label for="MARRIED_RG_1">No</label></td></tr></tbody></table>
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="radio_group" tabindex="-1" id="CHILDREN_RG">
<table class="radiogroup" datatable="0" role="presentation" summary="">
<tbody><tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" value="YES" name="children" id="CHILDREN_RG_0"><label for="CHILDREN_RG_0">Yes</label></td><td nowrap="nowrap">
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" value="NO" name="children" id="CHILDREN_RG_1"><label for="CHILDREN_RG_1">No</label></td></tr></tbody></table>
</fieldset>
```

Based on the above, I basically need a means of not repeating the radio group results - need the distinct values.

My code is something like the following:

```
$(':radio').each(function() { // loop through each radio button
        nam = $(this).attr('name'); // get the name of its set
        if ($(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length > 0) { 
        // see if any button in the set is checked
            alert(nam);
        }
    });
```

So based on this code using the above HTML, I get the correct values but because I am using a .each function, it is returning every line of the radiogroup, i.e.:

```
MARRIED_RG_0    YES
MARRIED_RG_1    YES
CHILDREN_RG_0   NO
CHILDREN_RG_1   NO
```

I only want to return:

```
MARRIED_RG_0    YES
CHILDREN_RG_1   NO
```

Comment: Please show the code you have now. It's a bit hard to say what's wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Apologies @Juhana - I will post what I have later on.

Comment: @Juhana - pls see updated thread with sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Juhana - does the same process apply for Checkboxes where there can be 1 or more selected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more clever way to do it, but you could first collect the list of radio button sets and then iterate through that list instead of every radio button.

```
var sets = [];

// first get all unique sets
$(':radio').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if ($.inArray(name, sets) === -1) {
        sets.push(name);
    }
});

// then loop through the sets
$.each(sets, function (index, set) {
    if ($(':radio[name="' + set + '"]:checked').length > 0) {
        // see if any button in the set is checked
        alert(set);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SF4qj/

Comment: Thanks @Juhana but is it also possible for each radiogroup to also just return the ID without the _0 or _1 at the end, so for MARRIED the id would just be: MARRIED_RG and for CHILDREN, it would just be: CHILDREN_RG ?

Comment: Yes, `.parents().find( 'fieldset' ).attr( 'id' )`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use anything different than .each(), you can try something like this:

```
$("input:radio[name='married']:checked").val()
$("input:radio[name='children']:checked").val()
```

Edited after question was clarified:
Try `$(this).is(":checked")` instead of `$(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length > 0`.

```
$('input:radio').each(function() { // loop through each radio button
    nam = $(this).attr('name'); // get the name of its set
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        alert(nam + ": " + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to use .each as I need to scan all fields on the page and grab their values. These items can be text box, radio group, checkbox etc.